fetch api is not working in Next js. giving error
NEXT.js
const API_KEY = process.env.API_KEY

import React from 'react'

const Home = async() => {
  const apiUrl = `https://api.themovie.org/3/movie/top_rated$?api_key=${API_KEY}&language=en-US&page=1`;

  const res = await fetch(apiUrl);
  console.log(res)
  try {

  if (!res.ok) {
    throw new Error('Failed to fetch data');
  }

  const data = await res.json();
  const results = data.results;
  console.log(results);
} catch (error) {
  console.error('Error fetching data:', error.message, 
"," ,error.response);
}

  return (
    <div>Home</div>
  )
}

export default Home

I tried the api on postman, and it worked. it looks the error started from the fetch method, above try-catch block. what's the problem here?

@David showing you the errors.

Looks like theres a typo in your api url, should be api.themoviedb.org.

I think its your env variabe, in next you have to prefix all env variables that you want on the client side with NEXT_PUBLIC_
so you should change all references from API_KEY to NEXT_PUBLIC_API_KEY.
If thats not the case it might be worth including the full error response and not just console.error('Error fetching data:'); like so:
console.error(error.response);


I gave the actual api key, but the same error

there is no "use client" and it's clearly a Server Component because it's async component which is only available for Server Component
